# UnsatisfiedLinkError when adding another dependency

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin, java-native-interface, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I successfully added a android library which comes with a .jar and a .so file. After adding the .so in `jniLibs/armeabi-v7a` and the .jar into `libs/`, I added in the module `build.gradle` the following: `implementation files('libs/mylib.jar')`.
This works just fine.

However, as soon as I add mailcore2-android-4.aar as dependency, the following error occurrs at the line when I first use an object of mylib:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for com.myLibPackage.myLib
```

I'm using Kotlin and the lib is written in Java. I've tried several ways to add the dependencies (separate modules, files), but the problem remains the same.

Comment: Am stuck on the same thing here. Were you able to solve it?